# Bluetooth adapter not found in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, bluetooth, acer

Since my upgrade to 16.04 the OS does not find the bluetooth-adapter anymore. The Laptop is an Acer Aspire V5-573G and all i can find about the bluetooth adapter is this: "Bluetooth Qualcomm Atheros Bluetooth 4.0". Here are some commands I executed, hope it helps:

Output of `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: 24:fd:52:ee:f4:b3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:18 memory:b3500000-b357ffff memory:b3580000-b358ffff
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       logical name: enp5s0f1
       version: 14
       serial: 08:9e:01:ce:3d:ac
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b3404000-b3404fff memory:b3400000-b3403fff
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 14)
```

Output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep Blue` does not have any output.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 046d:c051 Logitech, Inc. G3 (MX518) Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 046a:010d Cherry GmbH 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I added it. There's no bluetooth adapter in it, i think...

Comment: That's strange. Qualcomm bluetooth must be shown in lspci.

Comment: @p0wl  What OS were you using that bluetooth worked?

Comment: All previous Ubuntu versions and dualboot Windows.

Comment: My Acer Aspire laptop's Bluetooth adapter does not work using Ubuntu 16.04 too: http://askubuntu.com/q/791785/560233 Maybe we are facing a similar problem. I filed a bug report against the Linux kernel package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1597961

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. In my case I think it was a bug of my old installed version of unity control center, or some missing dependencies.
Resolved easily updating unity-control-center:

```
    sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Hope it may help.