# Bluetooth Adapter not found

Tags: bluetooth, adapter

[image]

I have dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire V 574 G. The bluetooth works fine in windows 10 but herein ubuntu the bluetooth setting says adapter not found.

And there is some information given on the back of the laptop that it has a WLAN+Bluetooth module.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e08e]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] [10de:1347] (rev a2)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2357:0601  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b520 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [8086:1604] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:9cb1] (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9cba] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9c90] (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:9c94] (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:9c96] (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9c98] (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller [8086:9ca6] (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9cc3] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:9c83] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9ca2] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] [10de:1347] (rev a2)
```

Output of `dmesg | grep Blue`:

```
[   16.053867] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   16.053882] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.053885] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.053887] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.053891] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.363156] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.363157] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.363160] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: What exactly are the make and model of the bluetooth adapter?

Comment: From Windows Device Manager, the device manufacturer says "Qualcomm Atheros Communications" and Location "Port_#0005.Hub_#0002"

Comment: And there is some information given on the back of the laptop that it has a WLAN+Bluetooth module. The image of the same is attached to my question(visit the link).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the question and put the output as requested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770897/problems-with-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @dobey It is not related at all.

Comment: @SugataRoy Can you also post output of `lspci -nn` and also `dmesg | grep Blue`

Comment: And check if it is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: No such bluetooth option present in BIOS I checked

Comment: Are the firmware files for the device in place?

Comment: Don't know. How to check?

Comment: Any help anyone?

Comment: I have Qualcomm Bluetooth adaptor if that helps

Comment: I have a Dell laptop which uses this same chip. Bluetooth works for me without any special config. But I do have a problem with bluetooth randomly switching off and then being available again only after I restart my machine.

Comment: @SugataRoy did you find any fix for this?

Comment: I followed the answer given on this page:
[Acer Bluetooth Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791785/qualcomm-atheros-bluetooth-4-0-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04/964350#964350)
And, it solved the problem at least for my Acer laptop. I don't know how but it just works.