# Bluetooth service start failed

Tags: virtualbox, bluetooth

Can someone assist with my error attempting to start bluetooth service:

```
Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Mon 2018-03-05 21:54:02 MST; 4min 32s ago
           ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth was not met
```

Comment: FWIW, https://askubuntu.com/questions/791785/qualcomm-atheros-bluetooth-4-0-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04 seemed to work. But I would love to know why this suddenly was a problem and how to unpack it. Was it related to a recent upgrade, or starting to use virtualbox?

Answer (score 1):

try to run below command,

```
apt-get install rfkill

rfkill list

rfkill unblock bluetooth

service bluetooth start
```

Comment: Why would you need to install rfkill as it is installed by default at least in non-server versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that bluetooth has been soft-killed by some application. Try lifting the block by

`rfkill unblock tpacpi_bluetooth_sw`

and start the bluetooth service by

`systemctl start bluetooth.service`