# wmgui will not connect to wiimote. Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

So I have my wiimote paired through the bluetooth program in settings with my mac mini running ubuntu 16.04 lts. As it is now all the buttons work as mouse buttons but I want to use wmgui and wminput so I can use the wiimote as a mouse and move the cursor. However, when I try to connect the wiimote using the program wmgui it says "could not connect" and in the terminal it says "no wiimotes found".

ETA: The output of rfkill list bluetooth is:

2: hci0: Bluetooth

ETA2:  sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0f0
       version: 01
       serial: 68:5b:35:84:dc:d7
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=57766a-v1.13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 02
       serial: 28:cf:e9:0e:0f:d5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.66 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:a0600000-a0603fff
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Edit 3

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 05ac:828a Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2512 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:01a4 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Wireless Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c219 Logitech, Inc. Cordless RumblePad 2
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c216 Logitech, Inc. Dual Action Gamepad
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `rfkill list bluetooth` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Information has been added. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: `sudo lshw -C network` might also be useful. Thank you.

Comment: information has been added. Any ideas??

Comment: I don't see a bluetooth device in your output. `lsusb` perhaps? Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/788502/bluetooth-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: output from that command is in edit 3. I dont get it I paired it under the bluetooth menu and the D pad works to scroll up and down in web pages on fire fox. the 2 button is the same as right click and the one button is left click. I just want to be able to move the mouse cursor now.

Comment: the wiimote is also listed under the bluetooth menu in the upper right hand corner of the screen.

Comment: VTR as I see the bluetooth adapter in the lsusb output now. Meanwhile you may find this useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup or perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27755/bcm2046-bluetooth-on-new-8-3-macbook-pro

Comment: So I can assign the buttoms and use the wiimote as a normal gamepad but I cannot figure out how to map it as a mouse. I tried to install wiican and that failed. I cant figure out moltengamepad. I think im about to throw in the towel.

Comment: @dox1842, were you able to get this working eventually, and do you remember how? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing (on a MacBook Pro 6,2 Mint 19.3) and am having very similar issues. If I pair it using the red button in the battery compartment, the D pad works like the arrows keyboard keys. Otherwise, I have the same errors.